# Finding nil when prepareForSegue Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am not at all sure why this is happening. When I try to use prefpareForSegue I get "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional values". I know what it means and where it is happening but I have no clue why.

There error happens on either of the lines marked in my code. I have already tested the values `dateText` and `currentDate` and neither are nil.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var DestViewController : CreatePostScrollViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CreatePostScrollViewController

    if dateText != "" {

        DestViewController.startTimeDateButton.setTitle(dateText, forState: .Normal)// Error Here

    } else if dateText == "" {

        DestViewController.startTimeDateButton.setTitle(currentDate, forState: .Normal)// Error Here
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's most likely `startTimeDateButton` which is nil

Comment: `destinationViewController` can't really be `nil` in this method... but it *could* possibly be the wrong type.  Either way, the real answer here is to stop using the crash operator.

Comment: What is the crash operator?

Comment: @Literphor I don't understand how `startTimeDateButton` can be nil

Comment: You need to do this validation in `DestViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method. Here its crashing because `startTimeDateButton` is not yet initialized,

Comment: I understand thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `prepareForSegue` is called, the user interface elements of the destination controller might not yet be initialized. What you should instead do, is have a field in CreatePostScrollViewController like this:

```
var buttonTitle: String?;
```

Then in your viewWillAppearMethod within CreatePostScrollViewController set the button's title to the buttonTitle field you have like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    if let buttonTitle = buttonTitle {
        startTimeDateButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal);
    }
}
```

Finally to finish the tale in the prepareForSegue do:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var DestViewController : CreatePostScrollViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CreatePostScrollViewController

    if dateText != "" {

        DestViewController.buttonTitle = dateText

    } else if dateText == "" {

        DestViewController.buttonTitle = currentDate
    }
}
```